# In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

I've been trying to get this array formula to work, but I get an error. It's just a `vlookup` array to display multiple columns. It works fine without the `{"";` bit, but I want it to drop down one row.

```
={"";ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($AA$4:$AA,CUSTOMER_DATA,{2,3,4,5,6},FALSE),""))}
```

Without

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($AA$4:$AA,CUSTOMER_DATA,{2,3,4,5,6},FALSE),""))
```

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## ...understanding the **`ARRAY_LITERAL ERROR`**:

- until both queries/filters/formulas output something then all is good:

  [image: 0]
- however if one of those queries/filters/formulas doesn't have anything to output it outputs **`#N/A`** - **`No matches are found in QUERY/FILTER evaluation.`**  - the issue is that **`#N/A`** is only in the 1st cell:

  [image: e]
- but array expects that matrix on both sides to be same (4 columns from both queries/filters/formulas):

  [image: 0]
- so we wrap each query into **`IFERROR`** and in case of error we output fake row with 4 fake columns - **`{"","","",""}`** - which will trick the array to output it like:

  [image: 0]
- therefore try like this:

  ```
  ={{"","","","",""}; 
   ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(AA4:AA, CUSTOMER_DATA, {2,3,4,5,6}, 0)))}
  ```

Comment: Wow, that makes a lot of sense, thank you. I'm going to build you a shrine.

Comment: Hi User0, Im getting the same issue with this formula? I've used your advice, but I can't see what I am missing. 
 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1srQaDqB_cYvSkPUB9_lnxncl3kbt6AJdKWfNIm-TrDk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: not sure what are you after but correct syntax should be: `={"header";TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Sheet1!A2:A,Sheet1!H2:H=A2))}`

Comment: Hi. I know this solution and it's very useful. I wonder if we can somehow avoid making additional row. When it's in the middle of stack, it makes empty row. Normally you can eliminate it using =query(table;"select * where Col1 is not null"). But I have a problem with this. My table have a mix of data types and QUERY messes up my data (assumes for example, that all the rows should be numbers and deletes string values). I've illustrated my problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69978650/query-formula-ignores-string-values